# Jquery UI table drag and drop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to drag and drop from one table to second table.

I have the jsfiddle working now. I want the dragged cell texts remain in the table 1 but I want dragged cell disappear when user drags the second table.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6n/6/

For example

if the user drags cell from table 1 to table 2. the html is like

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>drag1</td>
     <td>drag2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>drag3</td>
      <td>drag4</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
     <td>drag1</td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, if the user drag table 2 cell to another table 2 cell. The dragged cell texts disappear…like

```
<table>
   <tr> 
    <td>drag1</td>
    <td>drag2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>drag3</td>
    <td>drag4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>drag1</td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How do I accomplish this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
  $('.table:eq(1) td').on('drag',function(){
       $(this).text('');     
   });
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6n/8/)**

Comment: @Daniele As I see in the fiddle, when you drag a cell from the second table, its text disappears.